# Definition of PersonId of Type attributre not found

Tags: java

I am trying to delete the data in terms of the field - Person Id. When i try to do this i get the error as :
oracle.apps.fnd.framework.OAException: oracle.jbo.NoDefException: JBO-25002: Definition personId of type Attribute not found

Can someone guide me how to get it resolved.

This is the data that is present in my AM:

```
public void deletePersonMethod(String pAction, String pPersonId)
{
    System.out.println("Inside delete person method");
    NewTutorialVOImpl tutovo = getNewTutorialVO1();
    Row row[] = tutovo.getAllRowsInRange();

    for (int i=0;i<row.length;i++)
    {
        NewTutorialVORowImpl rowi = (NewTutorialVORowImpl)row[i];
        System.out.println("The Person Id is => "+ rowi.getPersonId());
        if(rowi.getPersonId().toString().equals(pPersonId))
        {
            rowi.remove();
            getOADBTransaction().commit();
            return;
        }
    }  
}
```

And the code present in my controller is :

```
public void processFormRequest(OAPageContext pageContext, OAWebBean webBean)
{
    super.processFormRequest(pageContext, webBean);
    String ActionInMainPersonScreen = pageContext.getParameter(EVENT_PARAM);
    String paramPersonId = pageContext.getParameter("paramPersonId");

    if(ActionInMainPersonScreen.equals("DeletePerson"))
    {
        Serializable paramDelete[] = {ActionInMainPersonScreen,paramPersonId};
        OAApplicationModule am = pageContext.getApplicationModule(webBean);
        am.invokeMethod("deletePersonMethod",paramDelete);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which line of code throws the first exception?

I don't know anything about this ORM framework, but the exception message you posted indicates that the property 'personId' isn't correctly defined on your NewTutorialVORowImpl entity.